# electron crash about OnNoMemory

Tags: crash, electron

Electron version 5.0.8 is used

```
base::`anonymous namespace'::OnNoMemory(memory_win.cc:52)
malloc(allocator_shim_override_ucrt_symbols_win.h:53)
v8::internal::AllocWithRetry(allocation.cc:119)
v8::internal::AccountingAllocator::GetSegment(accounting-allocator.cc:77)
v8::internal::Zone::NewExpand(zone.cc:157)
std::deque::push_back(deque:1541)
v8::internal::compiler::LoopFinderImpl::PropagateForward(loop-analysis.cc:310)
v8::internal::compiler::LoopFinder::BuildLoopTree(loop-analysis.cc:520)
v8::internal::compiler::LoopPeelingPhase::Run(pipeline.cc:1277)
v8::internal::compiler::PipelineImpl::Run(pipeline.cc:1009)
v8::internal::compiler::PipelineImpl::OptimizeGraph(pipeline.cc:1983)
v8::internal::compiler::PipelineCompilationJob::ExecuteJobImpl(pipeline.cc:955)
```

Is there any way to locate the problem with this crash or has anyone encountered how to fix it? Looking forward to reply

Comment: Could you provide a minimal code example that reproduces this bug?

Comment: This is an occasional dump on a project. I don't know when the crash happened. I can't provide a simple code example, but I can provide the corresponding dump